# AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-recyclerview

```
Lots of errors and I can't find the solution, it's a college project for mobile apps
```

https://github.com/ThalesCaruso/Lista-de-Mercado

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwcap.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEFik.png)

Watched a lot of youtube tutorials but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-beta02'
```

As per the [Room Declaring Dependencies guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies), you need to be using `annotationProcessor` for Java projects, not `implementation`:

```
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.0-beta02'
```

Comment: I'm using Java, isn't kapt just for Kotlin?

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to use `annotationProcessor` if you are in a Java project. I've corrected the answer.